# Animate table as rows are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I currently have the following piece of angular code:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    var items = [];
        $scope.addRow = function () {
        items.push({ value: 'Hello, world!' });
        $scope.items = items;
    }
}
```

Along with the following snippet of html:

```
<table ng-controller="MyController">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td>
            {{item.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="addRow()">Add row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As expected, each time I click `Add Row` a new row is added with the text `Hello, World!`.

How can I extend this so that the newly added row glows or flashes as it appears for a brief moment?  The idea being that in the real app the item will be added dynamically without a button click so I'd like to draw the users attention to the newly added item.

Comment: are you using/including the ng-animate module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907748/how-to-add-a-new-row-in-a-table-with-animation-using-jquery

Comment: @Clark, Those access the dom directly which you shouldn't do in angular, unless in a directive.

Comment: I'm currently not using jQuery, just angular. @PatrickEvans I'm currently only using what you see above.  Is ng-animate the way forward without relying on jQuery?

Comment: Try to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111411/angularjs-onchange-event-when-the-user-hits-enter

Answer (score 4):

if you include the ng-animate module you can use css classes(the ngAnimate page also shows how to use in javascript)

***http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate***

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items" class="slide">
    <td>
        {{item.value}}
    </td>
</tr>

<style type="text/css">
.slide.ng-enter, .slide.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.slide.ng-enter {  }        /* starting animations for enter */
.slide.ng-enter-active { } /* terminal animations for enter */
.slide.ng-leave { }        /* starting animations for leave */
.slide.ng-leave-active { } /* terminal animations for leave */
</style>
```

in the .ng-enter, .ng-leave classes you would specify the attribute you would want to animate, eg opacity,width,height etc

For triggering animations from javascript look for the ***JavaScript-defined Animations*** section of the ngAnimate page

For animation examples see http://www.nganimate.org

Answer (score 0):

im not a great angular developer but i think you need to use the ngAnimate directive, and then use css transitions, [here](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat) is an example from the oficial documentation